# Setting functions to onclick for Buttons within loops with strings in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var RelevantDiv = document.getElementById("RelevantDiv");
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
       var NewButton = document.createElement("NewButton");
       var IdString = "ID" + i + "_"  +j;
       NewButton.onclick = function() { DoStuff(IdString) };
       RelevantDiv.appendChild(NewButton);
    }
 } 

 function DoStuff(IdForStuff) {
    // Does stuff with id 
 }
```

The problem is that every time the `NewButton.onclick` is set, that it is setting it to the final `IdString` which is `"ID4_4"`.

Comment: What environment are you running in?  Is ES2015 available?  A simple switch from `var` to `let` would help if so.

Comment: @JamesThorpe needs to work for as many browsers, versions as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your underlying issue is that the variable being used within the `onclick` callback, `IdString`, is having its declaration [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top of the current scope, ie the function it's running within.  That means that every time you're within the loop, its value is overwritten - it's functionally the same as this:

```
var IdString;

var RelevantDiv = document.getElementById("RelevantDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var NewButton = document.createElement("NewButton");
      IdString = "ID" + i + "_"  +j;
      NewButton.onclick = function() { DoStuff(IdString) };
      RelevantDiv.appendChild(NewButton);
   }
}
```

You need to ensure that you capture the right value of `IdString` when you need it, which is typically done through the use of a closure:

```
var RelevantDiv = document.getElementById("RelevantDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      (function(IdString) {
          var NewButton = document.createElement("NewButton");
          NewButton.onclick = function() { DoStuff(IdString) };
          RelevantDiv.appendChild(NewButton);
      })("ID" + i + "_"  +j)
   }
}
```

Here we create another inner function to create a new scope to hold each individual `IdString` value.  It's then immediately called with the right value for each iteration of the loops.  `IdString` is then captured within this closure, and the correct value will be used within the `onclick` callback.

---

Alternatively, you can [bind the argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) at the moment you know what the relevant value is:

```
var RelevantDiv = document.getElementById("RelevantDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var NewButton = document.createElement("NewButton");
      NewButton.onclick = DoStuff.bind(null, "ID" + i + "_"  +j);
      RelevantDiv.appendChild(NewButton);
   }
}
```

This does away with both of the inner functions, and directly assigns the `onclick` event to a copy of the `DoStuff` function that will have the right argument.

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting, that you won't have such problems if you use `let` or `const`instead of `var`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
       const NewButton = document.createElement("NewButton");
       const IdString = "ID" + i + "_"  +j;
       NewButton.onclick = function() { DoStuff(IdString) };
       RelevantDiv.appendChild(NewButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: And still, every iteration it will be overwritten, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, if you replace `var` with `let` or `const` which are not hoisted, the problems disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that, when the handler you assign runs, the loop has already looped through all iterations, and the variable at that point will be at its final state. To avoid this, you need to use a lock. It involves a self-executing function `(function () { // code })()` which saves the current state of the variable. When the variable in the current iteration, for example `State 2` is given as an argument to the self-executing function, the scope of the function will save this state. When the for loop continues, the original variable will still change, but the scope of the new "inner function" will keep the value "locked". So even when the loop-variable will in the end be at its 4th state, the locked variable will still be in state 2.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    button.addEventListener ("click", function () {
        // Here, i would normally always be 5
        (function (lockedIndex) {
            // This lock will make i the way it should be
            // You have to use lockedIndex instead of i
        })(i)
    });
}
```

For your code, this would look something like:

```
 var RelevantDiv = document.getElementById("RelevantDiv");
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        (function (ix, jx) {
          var NewButton = document.createElement("NewButton");
          var IdString = "ID" + ix + "_"  +jx;
          NewButton.onclick = function() { DoStuff(IdString) };
          RelevantDiv.appendChild(NewButton);
        })(i, j)
    }
 } 

 function DoStuff(IdForStuff) {
    // Does stuff with id 
 }
```

Comment: `i` isn't the direct issue here, it's the fact that `IdString` is being hoisted.

Comment: Then, use the exact same method for IdString. I've just used i as example, it does not reference the ì` in your code.

Comment: Indeed, but your answer could be more detailed about the problem.

Comment: The problem isn't hoisting, it is the way values are shared with closures. @NikxDa solution solves this by passing the value on each iteration.

Comment: @NikxDa can you make this solution work for the string requested.

Comment: I can. Please give me a minute to do so.

Comment: @Lew The issue is exactly hoisting of `IdString`.  The solution in this answer skirts it by creating a new scope for `IdString` to live inside.